# ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) and Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: reactjs, express

bundle.js file is not loading in my html file when using express in react.
my project directory structure is

```
|-dist
|-node-modules
|-public
|--index.html
|-server
|--index.js
|-src
|--index.js
|-package.json
|-webpack.config.js
```

index.html file look like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/../dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <div id="root">Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and index.js in server directory looks like this

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require("path");
var app = express();

//var render = require("../dist/bundle");
app.get("/", (req,res)=>res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname+'/../public/index.html')));

var port = 8080;
app.listen(port,()=>console.log("Listening on port 8080"));
```

and webpack.config.js is

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry:"./src/index.js",
    output:{
        filename:"bundle.js",
        path:path.resolve(__dirname,"dist")
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                  presets: ['@babel/preset-env',"@babel/preset-react"]
                }
              }
            }
        ],
    },  
};
```

Comment: Make sure the path is correct

Comment: i added a temporary file hello.js in the public directory which has code console.log("hello"); and changed in script tag of index.html, it is generating same errors

Comment: problem is solved after adding app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname+'/../dist'))); in server/index.js file thanks